# Loop through categories in Magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I have several categories in my Magento shop and want to change their name. As you can loop through all products

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
                    ->load();
foreach($_productCollection as $_product) {
```

I thought there is a way to loop through categories too.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following code you can loop through categories.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIsActiveFilter();
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    echo $category->getName().', ';
}
```

OR

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
if ($ids){
    foreach ($ids as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);

        $entity_id = $cat->getId();
        $name = $cat->getName();
        $url_key = $cat->getUrlKey();
        $url_path = $cat->getUrlPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /var/customers/webs/Ihnken/scriptcategory.php on line 26

Comment: Ok. I updated answer. Please check alternate solution.